# How can I sync time between two ubuntu computers, not connected to the internet

Tags: ubuntu, time, ntp

I have two computers connected to each other over an ad-hoc wifi. How can I make the first computer always sync to the time of the second computer?

I tried playing with NTP, but could not figure out how to make it work in this situation.

Comment: I'm always reluctant to move questions to stackexchange sites that I don't use, but it seems to me that NTP configuration would get more answers on ServerFault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to install an NTP server on one of the computers and then modify the NTP settings on the other computer to look to that NTP server for it's time.

[UbuntuGeek has a detailed walkthrough on this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/network-time-protocol-ntp-server-and-clients-setup-in-ubuntu.html).